# Definition of Dihedral group via semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, dihedral-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group and let $\varphi:Z_2\rightarrow Aut(G)$ be the homomorphism where $\varphi(\overline{1})$ is the inversion automorphism.

Define $Dih(G)=G\rtimes_{\varphi} Z_2$.

Now set $G=Z_n$.

Then, does $(\overline{1}_n,0)$ represent the rotation in $D_n$ and $(0,\overline{1}_2)$ represent the reflection in $D_n$?

Moreover, the usual description of $D_n$ in abstract algebra texts are really informal. Even though $D_n$ can be defined using $O(n)$, I think the definition by semidirect product is really easy and natural, however I'm not sure whether this is the standard **formal** definition. What is the standard **formal** definition of $D_n$?

Comment: I think both these definitions are more or less standard, along with the two standard presentations ($\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^n=e, aba^{-1}=b^{-1}\rangle,\langle a,b\mid a^2=b^2=(ab)^n=e\rangle$ if I recall correctly). (And all are formal.)